# Set bar with lower value to foreground in histplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, histplot

When creating a histogram plot with seaborn, I would like to dynamically put the bar with the lower count to the front. Below is a minimal example where now the blue bar is always in the front, no matter its count. For example, in the second bin, I would like the orange bar to be in the front. Basically, I am looking for something similar to `multiple="stack"`, however without adding the columns up. Is that possible?

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
df_A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, 100), columns=["value"])
df_A["label"] = "A"
df_B = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, 100), columns=["value"])
df_B["label"] = "B"
df = pd.concat([df_A, df_B])
sns.histplot(df, x="value", bins=np.arange(0, 10, 1), hue="label")
```

[image: histogram]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop through the generated bar containers and compare the heights of corresponding bars. The order of the heights can then be used to set their z-order.  Optionally, you could set `alpha=1` to make them opaque.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()
df_A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, 100), columns=["value"])
df_A["label"] = "A"
df_B = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, 100), columns=["value"])
df_B["label"] = "B"
df = pd.concat([df_A, df_B])
ax = sns.histplot(df, x="value", bins=np.arange(0, 10, 1), hue="label")

for bar0, bar1 in zip(ax.containers[0], ax.containers[1]):
    order = np.argsort([bar0.get_height(), bar1.get_height()])
    bar0.set_zorder(4 - order[0])
    bar1.set_zorder(4 - order[1])
```

[image: z-order of histograms]

Here is an example with more hue values. `np.argsort` needs to be called twice to get the inverse order.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()
df = pd.DataFrame({"value": np.random.normal(0.01, 1, 4000).cumsum(),
                   "label": np.repeat([*"ABCD"], 1000)})
ax = sns.histplot(df, x="value", bins=30, hue="label", kde=True,
                  line_kws={'zorder': 10, 'lw': 3, 'ls': ':'})
num_groups = len(df["label"].unique())

for bars in zip(*ax.containers):
    order = np.argsort(np.argsort([b.get_height() for b in bars]))
    for bar, bar_order in zip(bars, order):
        bar.set_zorder(2 + num_groups - bar_order)
```

[image: ordering histograms depending on heights]

Here is how it would look like for matplotlib histograms (all created using the same bins):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
np.random.seed(123)
bins = np.arange(0, 1.001, 0.1)
ax.hist(np.random.rand(200) ** 0.5, bins=bins, label='A')
ax.hist(np.random.rand(100) ** 0.4, bins=bins, label='B')
ax.hist(np.random.rand(80) ** 0.6, bins=bins, label='C')
for bars in zip(*ax.containers):
    order = np.argsort(np.argsort([b.get_height() for b in bars]))
    for bar, bar_order in zip(bars, order):
        bar.set_zorder(2 + len(ax.containers) - bar_order)
ax.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlib histogram with lowest in front]